# Product view does not work after the search results page. Magento2

Tags: magento2, fatal-error

When I  go to the product view  through the catalog view page  after that it's

works when i go to from search result, but if i don't open product view trough

catalog view, when i go from search result to the product view , page is blank.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Maybe the problem is  cache ?

Comment: Is it showing any error? check the var/log  exception.log & system.log files

Comment: ABHISHEK TRIPATHI , there only system log, [2019-04-04 17:11:21] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-04-04 17:11:21] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-04-04 17:11:21] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []

Comment: [2019-04-04 17:11:21] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'paypal.partner.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-04-04 17:11:21] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'bml.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-04-04 17:11:21] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'home_services' tries to reorder itself towards 'form.subscribe', but their parents are different: 'page.wrapper' and 'footer' respectively. [] []

Comment: you are in developer mode?

Comment: ABHISHEK TRIPATHI, yes

Comment: paste this code in your index.php file `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` clean the cache & perform the steps again & see whether it is showing any error